# Roundup of HTML 5 vulgarizations and resources

Tags: resources, html, css

HTML 5 is going to change the game not just for developers but will also come into the lives of professionals of all trades have an online presence, and web amateurs. These people are not web professionals but HTML and Flash have both been an important part of their general culture of the web.

> **Vulgarization**: to  make  (a  technical
>   or  abstruse  work)  easier  to 
>   understand  and  more  widely  known; 
>   popularize.

*(credits to reference.com)*

What links do you know of vulgarizations of HTML 5 that can help friends, family and colleagues better understand these up and coming changes of the web. Resources on all HTML5 subjects welcome; Fonts, animation, audio, video, offline capabilities, ...

Here is a good start: [Scribd presentation on their adoption of HTML 5](http://www.scribd.com/doc/30964170/Scribd-in-HTML5)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217360/where-to-find-good-resources-to-learn-html-5-and-know-more-about-it

Comment: Lots of links here ˆˆ, thanks Marcel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/) - good collection of tutorial style articles
- [Mozilla Hacks](http://hacks.mozilla.org/) - frequently has posts on using cutting edge web stuff in Firefox development builds
- [HTML5 For Web Designers](http://books.alistapart.com/product/html5-for-web-designers) (Book) - haven't read it yet, but Jeremy Keith usually explains stuff very clearly
- [WHATWG HTML5 Forums](http://forums.whatwg.org/) - a bit more approachable than the mailing list

Answer (score 5):

1. http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/ - online Book
2. http://caniuse.com/ - Quick handy reference to compatability plus other stuff

Answer (score 0):

I good place to check the "readiness" of a feature.

http://html5readiness.com/

Answer (score 0):

There’s an author version of the spec, designed for people who are writing HTML5 (whereas the full spec also caters for people writing browsers etc.)

- http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/

It might be a bit technical for beginners, but for serious authors who don’t need the implementor stuff, it’s pretty good, and is as “official” as you can get.